# NPM Install Fail Node-SASS

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-sass

I trying to install a list of packages from my "package.json" archive to develop a Web Page but when I execute the comand "npm install" the following error appears:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\Documentos\\Desarrollo\\Plantillas\\Plantilla 2\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',        
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.3.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Documentos\\Desarrollo\\Plantillas\\Plantilla 2\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

The list of packages that I have on the "package.json" are the following:

```
{
  "name": "Flat-bootstrap-admin-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nextro is a admin template made using Bootstrap 4 framework.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Phoenixcoded",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssbeautify": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-inject": "^5.0.2",
    "gulp-minify": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sequence": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-smushit": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.6.9",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "components-jqueryui": "^1.12.1",
    "gmaps": "^0.4.24",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.16.0"
  }
}
```

I hope you could help me, I try to install node-sass V7.0 "alone" but I have the same error, the version of node,js that I have is 17.3.1.

Comment: try npm rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [upgrade to gulp-sass 5](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass#migrating-to-version-5).

The reason is that previous versions of gulp-sass, like the one that you are using, will automatically install an outdated version of node-sass, regardless of the version of node-sass specified in your package.json.

In your case, the old version of node-sass is in `D:\Documentos\Desarrollo\Plantillas\Plantilla 2\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass` as per error log.

Be careful to follow the upgrade instructions in the link above, because simply installing the new version won't work.